# Unable to validate RSS feed data in written in XML ('content:encoded' tag not recognized)

Tags: xml, validation, rss, rss-reader

I've recently setup my own blog and am writing an RSS feed for the blog. I intend to make a script to do it for me once I get the rules right, but for now, I am facing errors in validating the XML.

There RSS feed is [here](http://shreyans-sheth.me/blog/tuesdays-gone.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/res/preview.xsl"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Tuesday's Gone-bholagabbar</title>
    <link>http://shreyans-sheth.me/blog/gsoc/home.html</link>
    <description><![CDATA[This is bholgabbar's blog, 'Tuesday's Gone'. I (intend to) write about Programming, Algorithms and just about anything under the sun]]></description>
    <lastBuildDate>Tue, 26 Apr 2016 20:44:55 GMT</lastBuildDate>

    <item>
            <title>Hello World!</title>
            <link>http://shreyans-sheth.me/blog/home.html</link>
            <pubDate>Fri, 26 April 2016 14:34:13 +0000</pubDate>
            <description><![CDATA[GSoC '16 #awwwyea']]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[
                <p>And finally it's all paid off. Endless IRC conversations, reading code and tutorials I would barely understand at first and all those sleepless nights coding, waiting for mentor replies and the results.</p>
                <p>Selected for Google Summer of Code '16 with OpenMRS</p>
                ]]>
            </content:encoded>
        </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

When I try to validate the XML feed here: http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshreyans-sheth.me%2Fblog%2Ftuesdays-gone.xml

you can check the errors I get. I have been specifically asked to include a *content* tag in the field and idk but the data in the content feed is not being validated and showing up in the feed. There seems to be an issue with the date as well. What could be the problem?

Comment: The feed is now valid, feed validator gives only recommendations about `atom:link' tags. It is ok now?

Comment: No I had tried copying someones WordPress feed. Please refer to the feed code pasted in the question

Comment: @janih you seem to know your RSS, judging from your top tag. Could you help me out? My organization want's the 'content' tag somehow and I am unable to get that to run. What do you do?

Comment: Sure, Is the problem that you aren't sure how to make the feed valid OR is it that your changes are not showing in the feed as you say: "content feed is not being validated and showing up in the feed"

Comment: Let's say a mix of both. My organization want's me to add a 'content' tag which contains the content of my blog. Now when I add that content blog, it doesn't show up on my blog. Now when I validated the feed, it says that 'content' tag cannot be parsed or something. So there's the problem. I'll update the feed link to the one that's not working (it's the same as the code posted)

Comment: @janih Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to [declare namespace](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/howto/declare_namespaces.html) for [content](http://www.feedforall.com/content.htm):

```
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
<channel>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

This date `<pubDate>Fri, 26 April 2016 14:34:13 +0000</pubDate>` should be in form `<pubDate>Tue, 26 Apr 2016 14:34:13 +0000</pubDate>`. ('April' => 'Apr' and 'Fri' => 'Tue' to be valid)

After those changes, your example feed was valid. The validator also suggested adding `guid` elements and adding namespace for `atom:link`

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver and an absolute legend. Thank you! :D